# cakephp : Define Datasource for email plugin

Tags: email, plugins, cakephp-2.0, datasource

I have a problem with a datasoure configuration in cakephp email plugin , when I test my code  in local server , it's fine , but in hosting server I have error message :

```
Datasource class Emails.ImapSource could not be found.
```

that's my code :

```
public $emailTicket = array(
        'datasource' => 'Emails.ImapSource',
        'server' => 'xxxxx.com',
        'connect' => '{xxxxx.com:110/pop3/TLS/novalidate-cert}INBOX',
        'username' => 'contact@xxxxx.com',
        'password' => 'xxxxx',
        'port' => '143',
        'ssl' => true,
        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
        'error_handler' => 'php',
        'auto_mark_as' => array(
            'Seen',
            // 'Answered',
            // 'Flagged',
            // 'Deleted',
            // 'Draft',
        ),
    );
```

thank you for help !

Comment: Hi sir, did you figure out what the problem was? I;m currently in the same situation, and I m completely lost